# PHP Merging arrays with for loops without using array_merge function

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, array-merge

I am learning more about for loops and would like to see how do you merge arrays using only for loops and not using built-in PHP functions such as array_merge().

I know you can use foreach to do this, but how would this work using only for loops and not foreach?

foreach example:

```
$array1 = ['judas', 'john', 'michael'];

$array2 = ['fernando', 'jsamine', 'sam', 'walter'];

$array3 = ['judas', 'john', 'mike', 'steve'];

foreach ([$array1, $array2, $array3] as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $values) {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: your foreach is impossible.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh why?

Comment: foreach didn't work in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using just for loops.

```
$array1 = ['judas', 'john', 'michael'];    
$array2 = ['fernando', 'jsamine', 'sam', 'walter'];
$array3 = ['judas', 'john', 'mike', 'steve'];

$all_arrays = [$array1, $array2, $array3];
$merged = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $arr = $all_arrays[$i];
    $x = count($arr);
    for ($j=0; $j < $x; $j++) { 
        // Using the value as the key in the merged array ensures 
        // that you will end up with distinct values.
       $merged[$arr[$j]] = 1;
    }
}

// You could use array_keys() to do get the final result, but if you
// want to use just loops then it would work like this:
$final = [];
$x = count($merged);
for ($i=0; $i < $x; $i++) { 
  $final[] = key($merged);
  next($merged);
}

var_dump($final);
```

`key()` and `next()` ARE php functions. But I really do not know of a way to get to the keys without using either `foreach` or some php function.

Comment: I'm looking to do this with for loops not foreach.

Comment: Oops, I totally missed that part of the question. :( It's still possible. I will edit.

Comment: @cattywampus for loops. I saw another question from you the other day that was similar to this. I'm curious what your interest is in using for loops rather than foreach.

Comment: Just trying to get an understanding on how to use for loops in different situations. In other words for practice.

Comment: That's cool. I was just wondering. You probably know this, but usually a for loop is used in cases when you have a set number of times you need to do something. Using them to iterate arrays is generally going to be more cumbersome than foreach, especially if you need to access the keys.

Comment: Thanks for showing one possible way of doing this, it's definitely quite a bit more work an than using a foreach. But for learning purposes this was very helpful. Thank you again.

Comment: Question in the first for loop why is $i < 3? Because there's 3 arrays?

Comment: That's right. If you had an unknown amount of arrays, you could do it with `count($all_arrays)` instead, but if that was the case you would also have to address how to put an unknown number of arrays into `$all_arrays` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate each array on its own:

```
foreach($array2 as $v)
  if(!in_array($v, $array1))
    $array1[] = $v;
foreach($array3 as $v)
  if(!in_array($v, $array1))
    $array1[] = $v;
```

Or simply use array_merge() - there is no reason for do not do it.

Comment: Can this be doing using for loops? Not foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=array('1','2','3','4','5');
$b=array('a','b','c','d','e');
$c=count($b);
      for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) 
          {
             $a[]=$b[$i];  // each element  1 by 1 store inside the array $a[]
          }
print_r($a);
```

Comment: You need to pay attention to your code format in order for people to read easily your code.

Comment: The sample data in this under-explained answer does not resemble the asker's sample data / scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayMerge(array $arrays) {
    $mergeArray = [];

    foreach ($arrays as  $key => $array) {
        foreach($array as $finalArray) {
            $mergeArray[] = $finalArray;
        }
    }

   return $mergeArray;
}


$array1 = [
    'Laravel', 'Codeigniter', 'Zend'
];

$array2 = [
    'Node js', 'Vue js', 'Angular js'
];

$array3 = [
    'Python', 'Django', 'Ruby'
];

print_r(arrayMerge([$array1, $array2, $array3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$arr2 = array(2,5,6,7,8);
$allval = array();
foreach($arr2 as $key=>$val){
    $arr1[] = $val;
}
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v){
    if(!in_array($v,$allval)){
        $allval[] = $v;
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_R($allval);
```

Comment: The sample data in this unexplained answer does not resemble the asker's sample data / scenario.